# How do I scroll horizontally by more than one column at a time?

Tags: google-sheets

I have made a weekly planner: on the left is a frozen column with a list of times and then four-column blocks to represent each day. The first of every four columns has a date at the top.

I would like to be able to scroll (left and right) from day to day (date to date) rather than column by column.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sound like a rare instance where merging cells might be useful, for example merge horizontally each successive four cells in a row (a header perhaps) and tabbing across that row will jump four columns at a time.